# Programmatically setting a User Defined Runtime Attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, interface-builder

I added a User Defined Runtime Attribute to a `UIButton` using Interface Builder. The attribute is named `strokeColor`, and is of type `Color`.

I try to set it programmatically, as follows:

```
UIColor *someColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[myButton setValue:someColor forKey:@"strokeColor"];
```

The second line crashes, and I get the following error:

> *'*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key strokeColor.'*

What might be the cause of this exception? What data type does a user defined runtime attribute of type color expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runtime attributes allow you to access properties of objects *that would not otherwise be surfaced in Interface Builder*, but you still have to define any properties you are accessing via a runtime attribute. Simply adding a  runtime attribute to a class which doesn't have a matching property will throw an exception, as you have seen.

In your case, if you want to be able to set a property named strokeColor on a `UIButton` via a runtime attribute, first you must create a `UIButton` subclass or category that has the property, then you will be able to set it's corresponding runtime attribute;

Here's a `UIButton` category:

```
@interface UIButton (Coloring)

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *strokeColor;

@end
```

Comment: I added a runtime attribute called 'strokeColor' in interface builder. The setValue:forKey API is the way to set these runtime attributes programatically.

Comment: @HatchmasterJ Ah, completely misunderstood the problem. Updated.